# Create xml for soap web service?

Tags: php, xml, soap

ive been struggling for a few days now on creating a xml in PHP for a SOAP webservice with the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
<GetPaynetReference xmlns="http://www.test.com.mx/">
  <issuerCod>408ddf42-6426-45bf-b684-be6c864ed4d2</issuerCod>
  <description>test</description>
  <params>
    <Parameter>
      <Name>Reference</Name>
      <Value>123< Value/>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter>
      <Name>Amount</Name>
      <Value>10.0< Value/>
    </Parameter>
     <Parameter>
      <Name>DueDate</Name>
      <Value>31/08/2013< Value/>
    </Parameter>
  </params>
</GetPaynetReference>
```

can anyone point me in the right direction or provide a code example on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please show what you've tried and what happened when you tried it. Then we'll be able to help you move forward. Otherwise, your question will get downvoted and possibly closed. (On the other hand, if it's not a duplicate, this question has the potential to get some upvotes if you improve it a litte.)

Comment: http://php.net/soap - direction enough? Or anything in specific / any code you've written and than a problem with?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the [SoapClient library](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php).

Comment: hey, MK i am currently using soap client, i have previously created the xml simply passing an array, but the problem here is that i cant seem to create the correct xml structure due to the repeated nested elements such as parameter, name and value

Comment: well then your question is not well written.  Explain what you tried, what you got and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can look to something like nuSOAP. http://nusoap.sourceforge.net/. I use and is good.

Comment: NuSoap is no longer needed since PHP5 has built in SOAP support.